# Sign of Correlation between $X$ and $\log X$

Tags: correlation, expected-value, covariance

Suppose $\text{supp}(X)\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{\geq 1}.$  Can we say $$\text{Cov}(X,\log X)\geq 0?$$

On one hand, we can say by monotonicity of log and Jensen's inequality that $$X\geq E[X]\implies \log X\geq \log E[X]\geq E[\log X].\quad (1)$$

Now if it also holds that $$\log X\geq E[\log X]\implies X\geq E[X]\quad (2)$$

then $\text{sign}(X-E[X])=\text{sign}(\log X-E[\log X])$ and we are done, but I don't think $(2)$ necessarily holds.

Comment: Here is a suggestion. Try to prove/disprove it when $X$ is discrete. If it is true for in the discrete case, then you can try to generalize by using discrete approximations. In other words, find $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$, a sequence of random variables, which are monotonically increasing, and converge to $X$, then apply the monotone convergence theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sign requirement does not necessarily hold, but it's still possible to prove the result using an alternative method.  Since $x \log x$ is [convex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594300/why-is-x-logx-convex) and $\log x$ is concave (over the stipulated range), [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) gives:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(X) \log(\mathbb{E}(X)) &\leqslant \mathbb{E}(X\log X), \\[6pt]
\log(\mathbb{E}(X)) &\geqslant \mathbb{E}(\log X). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Applying each of these inequalities (in order) we get:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{Cov}(X,\log X) 
&= \mathbb{E}(X \log X) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(\log X) \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \mathbb{E}(X) \log(\mathbb{E}(X)) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(\log X) \\[6pt]
&\geqslant \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(\log X) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(\log X) \\[6pt]
&= 0. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: very nice...thanks ben!

Comment: Ben, I have added a helpful MathSE link. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: @User1865345: Don't mind at all.